# Replace Toast with Snackbar inner Class

Tags: java, android, snackbar

We would like to replace this Toast with a Snackbar in the code below
I have tried various configurations with close results but no prize
my best configuration would not accept `LENGTH_SHORT` in the make Snackbar

Can someone explain where to place the Snackbar code and perhaps why `LENGTH_SHORT` is not being accepted?

```
    private void addListenerOnButton_ADD() {
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(ETinput.getText().length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a Value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // REMOVE THIS Toast and insert Snackbar
                //======================================
                return;
            }
                    ......

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the EDIT

```
    private void addListenerOnButton_ADD(final AlteredCharSequence Snackbar) {
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(ETinput.getText().length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a Value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // REMOVE THIS Toast and insert Snackbar
                //======================================
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor( Color.RED)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            int Y = Integer.valueOf(ETinput.getText().toString().trim());
            int Z = Y + X;
            ETans.setText(String.valueOf(Z));

            //float Y = Float.valueOf(ETinput.getText().toString().trim());
            //float Z = Y + X;
            //ETans.setText(String.valueOf(Z));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please show how did you implement it(Snackbar), to show how to fix it

Comment: What exactly did you try?, some code perhaps that you tried to produce the Snackbar

Comment: @James_Duh, edit your original post adding your new code.  Also show the code that initializes the view variable.

Comment: @Gary Bak this EDIT will not let the LENGTH_LONG function it also altered this statement addListenerOnButton_ADD( Snackbar );

Comment: What is the point of the `final AlteredCharSequence Snackbar`?  Change the parameter name from `Snackbar` to something like `charSequence`

Comment: Why are you even using android.R.id.*?, the view passed in onClick should be enough

Comment: @Agu.Thade I just tried many configuration made the change to view tremoved the R.id the only issue now is LENGTH_LONG IDE tells me cannot resolve symbol also changed the parameter name as Gary Bak requested no results

Comment: @GaryBak no positive results from parameter name change see response to Agu.Thade above

Comment: @GaryBak am I missing compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' here is what I have in Gradle     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `view` from the `setOnClickListener` as the first parameter of the `Snackbar.make` method:

```
private void addListenerOnButton_ADD(final AlteredCharSequence Snackbar) {
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(ETinput.getText().length()==0){
                Snackbar.make(view, "Enter a Value", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("Action", null).show();
                return;
            }

            int Y = Integer.valueOf(ETinput.getText().toString().trim());
            int Z = Y + X;
            ETans.setText(String.valueOf(Z));

            //float Y = Float.valueOf(ETinput.getText().toString().trim());
            //float Z = Y + X;
            //ETans.setText(String.valueOf(Z));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your configuration still give me the LENGTH_LONG IDE tells me cannot resolve symbol  I hate to say this is becoming a major pain why is this so difficult

Comment: And could you also send me the code of your dependencies on your build.gradle file (module: app)?

Comment: the IDE suggest create Class create inner Class or Rename reference or  Introduce a local variable and the LENGTH_LONG remains RED

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'

Comment: tried adding  am I missing compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

Comment: Do you import the snackbar class: import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

Comment: yes but the word design is in red and no I did not import it but my imports have been happening automatic guess it did not SO I need to add a dependencie called design but is it a Library or WHAT ?

Comment: Yes, it's a lib that will allow you (among other things) to use the snackbar. Please, modify your answer and add all your build.gradle file so I can inspect it.

Comment: Thank You for following up YES we have working code which I will post the PROBLEM HERE was I did not have the widget Imported and the Dependencies were missing for Snackbar my Imports had been happening on automatic basis so my BAD

Comment: Is it working now? If so, please, accept my answer as correct

Comment: I tried to do that but not sure I can or that I know how I did click the arrow up but it said the code needed to be reviewed will try one more time

Comment: If you could edit your question putting your build.gradle file on it, I guess I could help you even more.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Snackbar snackbar;

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Enter a Value", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            if(ETinput.getText().length()==0){



    snackbar.show();

  return;
            }
                    ......

        }
    });
}
```

Use can `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE` if you want duration INDEFINITE and when you want to dismiss just use `snackbar.dismiss();`

Comment: this configuration still presents with errors any other thoughts

Comment: This answer is quite vague, it makes no attempt to explain that the 'view' variable mentioned is required as the base view for the SnackBar.   This view variable would have to be setup, possibly as a class member, and initialized before the snackbar creation.

Comment: @Vishwesh Jainkuniya IDE wants me to create CLASS or INNER CLASS or INTERFACE plus View view is declared below so the view in the make will be invalid null or just not used